# Factorizing $f(x) = 2x^4 +x^3 -x^2 +8x-4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried plugging in values of $x$ until I found $f(x)=0$. I got that $(x+2)$ is a factor. Is this the only way to find factors of this polynomial?

Then I used polynomial division to get $f(x) = (x+2)(2x^3 -3x^2+5x-2)$. However I tried different values of x but still couldn't get the cubic to equal zero. Does this mean the cubic has imaginary roots?

Also what does it mean for a polynomial to have imaginary roots? When you sketch them on the Ragland diagram, how does this bare relevance to the sketch of the function on the Cartesian plane?

Thanks

Comment: This polynomial has complex roots, but there is another real root you have not found. The cubic $2x^3 - 3x^2 + 5x - 2$ has the leading coefficient of $2$, so you might want to test if there are roots that are multiples of $\frac 12$. You will find one. Then the other two roots, which are complex, can be found by the usual quadratic root formula. (By the way, what is a Ragland diagram?)

Comment: Complex roots occur in pairs - so if you have a cubic, it has a real root.  You may not find it as easily as in this case though.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take *some* of the *guessing* out of finding rational roots by making use of the *[rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).* From Wikipedia:

> In algebra, the rational root theorem (or rational root test) states a constraint on rational solutions (or roots) of the polynomial equation
>
> $$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0 = 0$$
>
> with integer coefficients.
>
> If $a_0$ and $a_n$ are nonzero, then each rational solution $x$, when written as a fraction $x = p/q$ in lowest terms (i.e., the greatest common divisor of p and q is 1), satisfies
>
> - p is an integer factor of the constant term $a_0$, and
> - q is an integer factor of the leading coefficient $a_n.$

Using the Rational Root Theorem, we can check and confirm first that $-2$ is a root and $\frac 12$ is a rational root, and use polynomial long division to find the remaining quadratic:

$$f(x) = 2x^4 +x^3 -x^2 +8x-4 = (x+2)(2x^3 -3x^2+5x-2)=(x+2)(2x-1)(x^2-x+2)$$

Now, with only a quadratic left, we can find the roots of $x^2 - x + 2$ using the quadratic formula, and since $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = 1 - 8 = -7 < 0$, those roots will be complex roots: $$\dfrac {1 \pm \sqrt 7 i}{2}$$

So, $f(x) = (x+2)(2x-1)(x^2-x+2)$ has roots $$-2, \frac 12, \dfrac {1 \pm \sqrt 7 i}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

By [the Rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) we verify that $-2$ and $\frac 1 2$ are two rational roots for the given polynomial and we have by long division

$$f(x) = 2x^4 +x^3 -x^2 +8x-4=(x+2)(2x-1)(x^2-x+2)$$

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I found this very interesting method of visualing the complex roots of a quadratic equation: [Complex Roots Made Visible](http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10005.1.shtml).

I am not sure if there is a general rule that can be applied to higher degree polynomials but I found it a very interesting and unusual approach.

Comment: It seems this visualisation approach was also discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35992/intuition-building-visualizing-complex-roots) where there is mention of it also applying to cubic equations.